# Mongodb Updating the path would create a conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to insert new competitor if not exist, else only updating it, but im getting the following  error:

```
(node:4628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Updating the path 'competitors' would create a conflict at 'competitors'
```

This is my model regarding competitors:

```
competitors : [
{
    userid: {type: String, default: 'x'},
    amount:  {type: Number, default: 0},
    reward:  {type: Number, default: 0},

}
```

],

here is the piece of code that is running, but fails and reproduce the code

```
 var newInsertMent = {userid: user._id, amount: 0};
                return Competition_global.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {"competitors.userid": user._id, _id: globalCompetition._id},
                    { $addToSet: {"competitors": newInsertMent}, $inc: {"competitors.$.amount": amount}},
                    {upsert: true,new: true}
                    ).then(function (competitionUpdate) {
                    console.log(competitionUpdate);
                    return competitionUpdate;
                });
```

***Q: What am i doing wrong here, and why can it create a conflict?***

Comment: Try removing `amount` key in the `newInsertMent` object.  As the error states, that `amount` field will create a conflict with the subsequent `"competitors.$.amount"` update.

Comment: @chridam good idea. unfortunly its still a conflict.

Comment: How about using `$set` with the positional operator i.e. `{ $set: {"competitors.$.reward": newInsertMent.reward }, $inc: {"competitors.$.amount": amount}},`?

Comment: @chridam still conflict

Comment: with a rewrite in set, i get:  MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.@chridam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating the path 'x' would create a conflict at 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947772/updating-the-path-x-would-create-a-conflict-at-x)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing in my recent project and got the same error.
I solved my problem using two queries

First, let find the User is present and store the result

```
  let result = Competition_global.findOne(
{"competitors.userid": user._id, _id: globalCompetition._id}
  });
```

By using the result if the user not found then push the new user object in the competitors array

```
  if (result === null) {
    let result = await Competition_global.insertOne(
      {
        $push: {
         // your new user data
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

else Update the user amount

```
else {
    let result = await Competition_global.updateOne(
      {"competitors.userid": user._id, _id: globalCompetition._id},
      {
          $inc: {"competitors.$.amount": amount},
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue [#7003](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7003) of mongoose (and may be mongodb)