# Updating the path 'x' would create a conflict at 'x'

Tags: mongodb, upsert

This error happens when I tried to update upsert item:

```
Updating the path 'x' would create a conflict at 'x'
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Field should appear either in `$set`, or in `$setOnInsert`. Not in both.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. "$set" happens if the document is found, "$setOnInsert"  if the document is not found. There's no conflict since both will never be applied at the same time. If you can't use both on the same field, that kind of defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: `$set` happens if the document is found *and* if it's not found. Therefore it conflicts in "not found" state on `$setOnInsert` and `{upsert: true}`. Seems like MongoDB developers could not define priority of one over another :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. There should really be a "$setOnUpdate" operator.

Comment: As the mongodb document, it applies the $set and $setOnInsert operations to this document. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

Comment: Just yeah, don't duplicate fields. No one have mentioned that, but  $setOnInsert is actually adding those fields to update doc. Just specify which fields you want to be inserted on insert and update doc excluding properties from insert doc.

Comment: at least the error message could have been better

Comment: But what if I want to insert a document if it doesn't exist, and update just one field if it exists? Both must have the `x` field.

Comment: @emremrah at lease in javascript you can do `$set:{x: defaultValue, ...data}` without the `$setOnInsert`, so if x is in data then it would override the default value.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem while performing an **update** query using PyMongo.
I was trying to do:

```js
> db.people.update( {'name':'lmn'}, { $inc : { 'key1' : 2 }, $set: { 'key1' : 5 }})
```

Notice that here I'm trying to update the value of `key1` from two **MongoDB Update Operators**. 
This basically happens when you try to update the value of a **same key** with more than one **MongoDB Update Operators** within the same query. 
You can find a list of Update Operators over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Answer (score 15):

You cannot have the same path referenced more than once in an update. For example, even though the below would result in something logical, MongoDB will not allow it.

```
db.getCollection("user").updateOne(
  {_id: ...},
  {$set: {'address': {state: 'CA'}, 'address.city' : 'San Diego'}}
)
```

You would get the following error:

```
Updating the path 'address.city' would create a conflict at 'address'
```

Answer (score 13):

If you pass the same key in `$set` and in `$unset` when updating an item, you will get that error.

For example:

```
const body = {
   _id: '47b82d36f33ad21b90'
   name: 'John',
   lastName: 'Smith'
}

MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(body._id, { $set: body, $unset: {name: 1}})

// Updating the path 'name' would create a conflict at 'name'
```

Answer (score 10):

```
db.products.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  {
     $set: { item: "apple" },
     $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Below is the key explanation to the issue:

> MongoDB creates a new document with _id equal to 1 from the 
> condition, and then **applies the $set AND $setOnInsert operations to
> this document.**

If you want a field value is set or updated regardless of insertion or update, use it in $set. If you want it to be set only on insertion, use it in $setOnInsert.

Here is the example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#example

Comment: For me the issue was that same field ("dateUpdate") appeared in both operators. I left "dateUpdate" only in $set and solved my problem.

Comment: WTF - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from MongoDB 4.2 you can use aggregate pipelines in update:

```
db.your_collection.update({
    _id: 1
}, 
[{
    $set:{
        x_field: {
            $cond: {
                if: {$eq:[{$type:"$_id"} ,  "missing"]},
                then: 'upsert value',   // it's the upsert case
                else: '$x_field'    // it's the update case
            }
        }
    }
}],
{
     upsert: true
})
```

db.collection.bulkWrite() also supports it

Comment: how is your example a aggregate pipelines? please explain?

Comment: db.collection.bulkWrite() works

Answer (score 2):

With the Ruby library at least, it's possible to get this error if you have the same key twice, once as a symbol and once as a string:

```
db.getCollection("user").updateOne(
  {_id: ...},
  {$set: {'name': "Horse", name: "Horse"}}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue while using the query below.

```
TextContainer.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId, 'content._id': req.params.noteId }, { $set: { 'content.note': req.body.note } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

When i have changed `'content.note'` to `'content.$.note'` it has been fixed. So my final query is :

```
TextContainer.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId, 'content._id': req.params.noteId }, { $set: { 'content.$.note': req.body.note } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

I observed that there is no direct solution mentioned here for this error.
In my case, I was removing an ID from my schema list and also adding a new ID at the same time and got this error.

Earlier code :

```
const findProject = await ProjectSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
        { projectId },
        { 
          $addToSet: { projectPolicyList: policyId },
          $pull: {projectPolicyList: oldPolicyId} 
        }
    );
```

So, a simple workaround for this is to update the list one at a time. In my case, I first added new element and then deleted from the list.

Correct Code :

```
const pushProjectPolicyList = await ProjectSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId,
  { $addToSet: { projectPolicyList: policyId } });

const pullProjectPolicyList = await ProjectSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId,
  { $pull: { projectPolicyList: oldPolicyId } });
```