# Updating the path 'packages.$[pkg10].items' would create a conflict at 'packages'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do following update in mongo, and getting error:

```
db.xyz.updateOne(
    { "xyzId": 1 },
    {
        $push: { "packages": { "id": 11 } },
        $pull: { "packages.$[pkg10].items": { "id": 1000 } }

    },

    {
        arrayFilters: [{ "pkg10.id": 1 }]
    }
)
```

Error:

```
{
    "message" : "Updating the path 'packages.$[pkg10].items' would create a conflict at 'packages'",
    "stack" : "script:1:11",
    "name" : "WriteError",
    "code" : 40,
    "index" : 0
}
```

My question is why this is not able to first add one package in order and then remove item from another specified package ?
And how can I know which kinds of updates can lead this type of error.

Similar Question,(but was not helpful): [Updating the path 'x' would create a conflict at 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947772/updating-the-path-x-would-create-a-conflict-at-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I know which kinds of updates can lead this type of error

If you try to `update the same path i.e packages` in the same update operation.

Here, you have `pull` and `push` on `packages`. Hence the error occurred. If you have to update another `path` or `field`, you can add it in the same update operation.

> why this is not able to first add one package in order and then remove item from another specified package

It's a restriction/feature-missing. It's the way in mongo db.