# Mongo 5 findOneAndUpdate aggregation pipeline for default counter value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Theres a several old questions (2015/2016) about doing an upsert with $inc that has a default value. The consensus seemed to be do multiple DB calls. I'm hoping there is a more modern approach to this now. I'm using Mongo 5.0.9.

I found this example that states you can now use $cond in update aggregation pipelines. I tried the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62819768/1795570

Trying to convert it to my problem I came up with:

```
const result = await context.params.tenantDb.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate({
    // Filter
    name: options.name,
  }, {
    // Data
    $set: {
      value: {
        $cond: {
          if: {$eq:[{$type:"$value"} ,  "missing"]},
          then: 1000,   // it's the upsert case
          else: { // it's the update case
             $inc: {
               value: 1
             }
          }    
       }
      },
    },
  }, {
    // Mongo Options
    returnDocument: 'after',
    name: options.name,
    upsert: true,
  });
```

This however just adds the entire $cond as the value to my document.

```
 value: {
    _id: new ObjectId("62ab8829d8ea984d839e10f3"),
    name: 'my_counter',
    value: { '$cond': [Array] }
  },
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: is the default value "missing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to achieve that with this, you're missing [] that will help you to use the aggregation framework, then you should have this

You will be able to achieve that with this, you 're missing [] that will help you to use the aggregation framework, then you should have this

```
const result = await context.params.tenantDb.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate({
    // Filter
    name: options.name,
}, [{
    $set: {
        value: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $eq: [{
                            $type: "$value"
                        },
                        "missing"
                    ]
                },
                then: 1000,
                // it's the upsert case
                else: {
                    $add: [
                        "$value",
                        1
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

    }
}], {
    // Mongo Options
    returnDocument: 'after',
    name: options.name,
    upsert: true,
    multi: true
});
```

Comment: @JoeJankowiak, notice the square brackets in the update - it's relatively new "aggregation update" feature. It's a good solution, I would only reverse the condition to compare type do "double" so you don't attempt to increment non-numerical values. Also, if you are concerned about new documents only  - there is "$setOnInsert"

Comment: Good suggestion on comparing to double instead. As for $setOnInsert can you give an example? I tried using $setOnInsert and $inc but that gives a conflicting path error since both are trying to change "value".