# Updating the path would create a conflict mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to push to a document then set isDefault to false for all except for the one I want to set. I am having issues setting it as I am getting `MongoError: Updating the path 'cards' would create a conflict at 'cards'`

this is my query

```
    const update = { 
                
                $push: { cards: card },
                $set : { 'cards.$[].isDefault': false },
            };

const query = { id: customer.id }

this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
                query,
                update,
                { new: true },
                (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }

                    if (!result) {
                        return reject(
                            new ModelNotFoundError(
                                `${this.name} not found update with operators`
                            )
                        );
                    }

                    resolve(result);
                }
            );
```

This is what my data structure looks like

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    cards: [
      {
        name: "Shipit",
        fee: 4,
        isDefault: false
      },
      {
        name: "Shipit",
        fee: 3,
        isDefault: true
      }
    ],
    
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cards: [
      {
        name: "Shipit",
        fee: 3,
        isDefault: true
      }
    ],
    
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947772/updating-the-path-x-would-create-a-conflict-at-x

Comment: It is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the update (works without any errors and the result is as expected), using the Updates With Aggregation Pipeline feature (requires MongoDB v4.2+).

```
update = [
  { $set: { 
    cards: { 
      $map: { 
        input: "$cards", 
        in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { isDefault: false } ] }
      }
    }
  } },
  { $set: { 
    cards: { 
      $concatArrays: [ "$cards", [ card ] ] 
    }
  } }
]
```

The error you are getting is due to performing two update operations (`$set` and `$push`) on an array field.

Comment: This does not give an error again but isDefault values of previous cards does not change to false. They remain true.

Comment: I am using mongo 5.0.10

Comment: Also I deleted my DB and recreated it but now cards aren't getting saved at all.

Comment: I will check what the issue is and get back to you shortly.

Comment: I am assuming the value of `card` in your code is something like this: `{ "name" : "new card 9", "fee": 9, "isDefault" : true }`

Comment: I tried the query in `mongo` shell connecting to MongoDB version 4.2. The update query works fine with `collection.findOneAndUpdate` method.

Comment: For some weird reason, this works in in Monogoplayground but doesn't work in my code. and does not throw any error.

Comment: But $push works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, timezone difference.